# GtkSpinButton disabled by default in Glade

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I added GtkSpinButton to my dialog from Glade and it is disabled by default:

[image]

What should I do to make arrows enabled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to configure the GtkSpinButton with the Adjustment object as follows (example values):

```
adj = gtk.Adjustment(1, 1, 99, 1, 1, 1)
spinBtn = self.builder.get_object("spinbutton1")
spinBtn.configure(adj, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I thought I can set it up from Glade. Can I?

Comment: umpirsky, try to create a new Adjustment widget by selecting it in the Miscellaneous section in the Palette view of the Glade app. Set your adjustment up in the Properties view with the appropriate values, then select your GtkSpinButton widget in the widget tree, go to spin buttons' Properties view and add your Adjustment (Adjustment field goes next after the buttons' Name text field) to it. I use Glade 3.6.7.